# Horner's rule for polynomial evaluation

Tags: kotlin

Any better ways to implement 'inverseIndices'? Please give me feedback regarding good coding conventions.

```
fun main(arg: Array<String>) {
    //− 19 + 7 x − 4 x 2 + 6 x 3
    val coefficients = arrayListOf<Int>(-19, 7, -4, 6)
    val x = 3
    var result: Int = 0
    for (i in coefficients.inverseIndices) {
        result = (result*x) + coefficients[i]
    }
    println(result)
}



val ArrayList<Int>.inverseIndices: IntProgression
    get() = (size -1).downTo(0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you can use [`.reversed()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reversed.html) or  [`.asReversed()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/as-reversed.html) to reverse the list of `coefficients` and iterate over it, without working with the indices:

```
coefficients.asReversed().forEach {
    result = (result * x) + it
}
```

Also, you can use the [functional idiom of *fold/reduce*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)), and replace iteration with folding the list (here, [`.foldRight(...)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold-right.html) is used to fold the collection from its end):

```
val x = 3
val result = coefficients.foldRight(0) { it, acc -> it + acc * x }
```

Answer (score 2):

This has been well answered by @hotkey already.  I also encourage you to use fold/reduce.

Although you don't need `inverseIndices`, I have a comment on it.  You should always strive for the most general function definitions, even if it seems at first that you need it only for a particular problem.  So in that case:

```
val <T> Collection<T>.inverseIndices: IntProgression
    get() = (size - 1).downTo(0)
```

I'm implementing on any `Collection` of just `ArrayList` and for any generics instead of just `Int`s.

Something that you might want to consider for performance is using `IntArray` instead of `ArrayList<Int>`.  It might be useful for performance in some cases, but it has the downside of not being usable with generics.